# Почему не установливается Google Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu

Переустановил убунту 16.04, собирался устанвить гугл хром браузер, при установке пишет следующее...  this software comes from a 3rd party В чем причина? Как можно исправить?

Comment: При установке выбирал этот пакет  64 bit .deb (для Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: OS TYPE - 64 bit

Comment: https://www.google.ru/chrome/index.html

Comment: По моему, оттуда тоже пробовал, но сейчас еще раз попробую

Comment: пишет  this software comes from a 3rd party

Comment: а если через диспетчер приложений ?

Comment: Там нету хрома..

Comment: вообще может быть это будет полезно : https://www.technig.com/install-3rd-party-software-ubuntu/

Comment: Вопрос остался нерешенным.

Comment: Ты ставил через добавление репы гугла или как-то по-другому?

Comment: ```cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list``` Есть тут что-то?

Comment: Используй apt: apt install chromium-browser

Comment: По юзабельности - ничем не отличается. - зато будет корректно обновляться. что касается вопроса , вот тут советуют использовать gdebi : https://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center